# Strange behaviour with TextBox not showing string properly

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, string-formatting

Here is the text assigned to the `Text` property(pardon the bad quality):

[image]

I have copied the text straight from the `TextBox` on the form, copied it into notepad++ and shown all characters. As you can see everything is well aligned.

Here is how the `TextBox` looks in the form:

[image]

It seems the spacing is now all screwed up. What could be the problem?

Edit: The TextBox is set to true for MultiLine, ReadOnly and WordWrap.

Comment: Use a fixed-pitch font like Notepad++ does so the letters have the same width as the spaces.  Pick, say, Consolas or Courier New.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your textbox is using a variable-size font.

Notepad++ is using a fixed-width font.

Make your textbox use Courier New font and you will see it lines up.